# Implementing a simple ResNet block with PyTorch

Tags: python-3.x, deep-learning, pytorch, resnet

I'm trying to implement following ResNet block, which ResNet consists of blocks with two convolutional layers and a skip connection. For some reason it doesn't add the output of skip connection, if applied, or input to the output of convolution layers.

The ResNet block has:

- Two convolutional layers with:

  - 3x3 kernel
  - no bias terms
  - padding with one pixel on both sides
  - 2d batch normalization after each convolutional layer
- The skip connection:

  - simply copies the input if the resolution and the number of channels do not change.
  - if either the resolution or the number of channels change, the skip connection should have one convolutional layer with:

    - 1x1 convolution without bias
    - change of the resolution with stride (optional)
    - different number of input channels and output channels (optional)
    - the 1x1 convolutional layer is followed by 2d batch normalization.
- The ReLU nonlinearity is applied after the first convolutional layer and at the end of the block.

My code:

```
class Block(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_channels, out_channels, stride=1):
        """
        Args:
          in_channels (int):  Number of input channels.
          out_channels (int): Number of output channels.
          stride (int):       Controls the stride.
        """
        super(Block, self).__init__()

        self.skip = nn.Sequential()

        if stride != 1 or in_channels != out_channels:
          self.skip = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(in_channels=in_channels, out_channels=out_channels, kernel_size=1, stride=stride, bias=False),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(out_channels))
        else:
          self.skip = None

        self.block = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(in_channels=in_channels, out_channels=out_channels, kernel_size=3, padding=1, stride=1, bias=False),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(out_channels),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Conv2d(in_channels=in_channels, out_channels=out_channels, kernel_size=3, padding=1, stride=1, bias=False),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(out_channels))

    def forward(self, x):
        out = self.block(x)

        if self.skip is not None:
          out = self.skip(x)
        else:
          out = x

        out += x

        out = F.relu(out)
        return out
```

Comment: Please, define "it doesn't work"

Comment: @Berriel It doesn't add the output of skip connection, if applied, or input to the output of convolution layers for some reason

Comment: Let me know if my answer helped you

Comment: @Berriel, Your solution was helpful, thanks :)

Comment: The dimensions of the last Conv2d in the sequential is wrong, the in_channels should be equal to out_channels

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is in the reuse of the `out` variable. Normally, you'd implement like [this](https://github.com/pytorch/vision/blob/793b647cb98eba786fb301744a7d63f67c5ca5d0/torchvision/models/resnet.py#L101-L121):

```py
def forward(self, x):
    identity = x
    out = self.block(x)

    if self.skip is not None:
        identity = self.skip(x)

    out += identity
    out = F.relu(out)

    return out
```

If you like "one-liners":

```py
def forward(self, x):
    out = self.block(x)
    out += (x if self.skip is None else self.skip(x))
    out = F.relu(out)
    return out
```

If you *really* like one-liners (please, that is too much, do not choose this option :))

```py
def forward(self, x):
    return F.relu(self.block(x) + (x if self.skip is None else self.skip(x)))
```

Answer (score 0):

BTW, the input_channel of the second Conv2d should keep the same as the output_channel of the first Conv2d.

```
self.block = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Conv2d(in_channels=in_channels, out_channels=out_channels, kernel_size=3, padding=1, stride=1, bias=False),
        nn.BatchNorm2d(out_channels),
        nn.ReLU(),
        nn.Conv2d(in_channels=out_channels, out_channels=out_channels, kernel_size=3, padding=1, stride=1, bias=False),
        nn.BatchNorm2d(out_channels))
```